# Using pinvoke to pass embedded array of C structs inside struct array to c#

Tags: c#, c, dll, struct, pinvoke

I am attempting to use an array of structures to pass data to/fro my C# ui and my C dll.
 Further complicating matters is that the structure contains another array of structures.
 I have figured out how to the simpler stuff using pinvoke, but how do I declare
 the embedded structures, and how do I pass them?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public class csForm {
    public int endDate;   
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 128)]
    public char[] formId;
}

 [DllImport("myDll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
 public static extern void fillForm([In, Out] csForm data, 5);

// c code
typedef struct s_ptxRow {
int ptxNumber;
char primitive[128];
int primitiveParams[128];
} ptxRow;

typedef struct s_workSpace{
char formId[128];
int endDate;
ptxRow PtxRow[128];
} cForm;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) fillForm(cForm csForm[], interface csFormCount)
{

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < csFormCount; ++i)
    {
        j = int / 2;
        csForm[i].endDate = i;
        strcpy(csForm[i].formId, "formId here");

        csForm[i].PtxRow[j].ptxNumber = i;
        csForm[i].PtxRow[j].primitiveParams[i] = i;
        strcpy(csForm[i].PtxRow[j].primitive, "someText");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were going in the right direction. You just needed to declare the `ptxRow` structure in C# and then add an array of it to `csForm`. You even don't need to allocate any arrays beforehand - apparently P/Invoke does it for you since it knows their sizes. The entire sample code is included because there were minute errors in some declarations.

*Note: When I tried to use classes in C# I got strange results (e.g. incorrect member and pointer values in the C++ code) which led to various errors. Switching to structs made the problem go away. I think this has something to do with reference and value types, but would appreciate input from more knowledgeable people. I'm testing with .NET 3.5 if it matters.*

```c
#include <string.h>

typedef struct s_ptxRow {
    int ptxNumber;
    char primitive[128];
    int primitiveParams[128];
} ptxRow;

typedef struct s_workSpace {
    char formId[128];
    int endDate;
    ptxRow PtxRow[128];
} cForm;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void fillForm(cForm csForm[], int csFormCount)
{
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < csFormCount; ++i)
    {
        j = i / 2;
        csForm[i].endDate = i;
        strcpy(csForm[i].formId, "formId here");

        csForm[i].PtxRow[j].ptxNumber = i;
        csForm[i].PtxRow[j].primitiveParams[i] = i;
        strcpy(csForm[i].PtxRow[j].primitive, "someText");
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace PInvokeStructsCS
{
    class Program
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public struct PtxRow
        {
            public int ptxNumber;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 128)]
            public char[] primitive;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 128)]
            public int[] primitiveParams;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public struct csForm
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 128)]
            public char[] formId;
            public int endDate;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 128)]
            public PtxRow[] ptxRow;
        }

        [DllImport("PInvokeStructsC.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern void fillForm([In, Out]csForm[] data, int count);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            csForm[] forms = new csForm[2];

            try
            {
                fillForm(forms, 2);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```